# How do I recover deleted browser history on iPhone?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I accidentely deleted the browser history in Safari on the iPhone, but would still need to re-access one link. How can I recover a deleted browser history?

Answer (score 1):

Not endorsing this practice, but yes, there is a way that sometimes works...

Go to Settings, then Safari, then scroll to bottom and select 'Advanced' and then 'Website Data'. Selecting from there should show you history.

Answer (score -1):

It is a difficult thing to retrieve the deleted browser history if you don't have backups, but don't worry, if the data are still not overwritten, there is a strong possibility that deleted browser history can be retrieved with some professional tools.